# Given inventory quantity, how many sellable items will I have given an item is sold on a buy 4 get 1 free basis

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For a certain item, I have a specific inventory quantity of $333$ items. I have a sales rule of buying $4$ and get 1 free. Given the stock amount, how can I calculate how many sellable items I have?

I did the calculation manually with trial and error and found out that I can sell $264$ items and give $66$ items for free which would add to $330$ hence I will have 3 items in hand.

I am looking for a formula that I can apply to excel and retrieve all the above numbers individually. E.g. Total Sellable: $264$ Total Free: $66$ Stock Left: $3$.

I have many more inventory items with different sales rules e.g. buy 10 get 3 free hence cannot do it all manually and I could not find a way to calculate this in a formula.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: With the rule 4+1 you have to divide the total by 5 and round the result to get 66. This means 66 lots of 4+1: i.e. 66 x 4 sold and 66 gift.

Comment: If the rule is 10+3 divide 333 by 13 and round it: 25.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In each sale, you give customers $n$ items although they pay only for $m<n$ of them. If the stock is $s$, you can make $\lfloor\frac{s}{n}\rfloor$ such sales. The total sellable items are $\lfloor\frac{s}{n}\rfloor m$, total free  $\lfloor\frac{s}{n}\rfloor (n-m)$ and the stock left $s-\lfloor\frac{s}{n}\rfloor n$. If you are using Excel, you can implement the floor function using `Int()`.